# How to add a row to a matrix in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a 2*2 matrix called orders:

0 0

0 0

created by:

```
set orders matrix:from-row-list [[0 0] [0 0]]
```

and I would like to change it to be a 3*2 matrix:

0 0

0 0

10 50

How to do this please? (I guess you have to create a new matrix also called orders to overwrite the existing orders, but I couldn't figure out the syntax.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to first convert your matrix to a list, than add the new row to the list, and convert it back to a matrix. Not very elegant, but the report function below should do the trick:

```
extensions [ matrix ]

to-report matrix-add-row [matrix row-added]

  let temp-list matrix:to-row-list matrix ;; converts the matrix to a list
  set temp-list lput row-added temp-list ;; the new row is added to the list
  report matrix:from-row-list temp-list ;; converts the list back to a matrix

end

to test

  let orders matrix:from-row-list [[0 0] [0 0]]
  show orders
  show matrix-add-row orders [ 10 50 ]

end
```

This would return you:

```
observer> test
observer: {{matrix:  [ [ 0 0 ][ 0 0 ] ]}}
observer: {{matrix:  [ [ 0 0 ][ 0 0 ][ 10 50 ] ]}}
```

Of course, you have to make sure that the dimensions of the matrix and the row added match.

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful. Working with lists/arrays/matrices/tables is by far the most frustrating thing about NetLogo and it seems to be because lists are immutable objects. It seems difficult to believe NL has to be that way because of technical reasons so I wonder why they do it.

Comment: I don't want to start an argument about this but NL should be about creating a target of an object - as closely as is necessary - that can be experimented on; everything else should be secondary to this. For instance, with the models in the library that are modelling human behaviour (and presumably animal behaviour) - it does not feel like our memory is immutable. In fact, sometimes I use a mnemonic like Richard Of York Gave...to recall a list, and then if the list needs to change I will create a second mnemonic to remember just the change - it doesn't feel like I am creating a second list.

Comment: *in the above I should have said 'agent modelling should be about creating...' rather than 'NL should be about creating...'

Comment: Mutability makes certain programming tasks easier, but also opens a terrifying Pandora's Box of potential bugs when mutable values are shared between different parts of the code (or between different agents) and then modifications made in one place unexpectedly show up somewhere else. I strongly believe that in the big picture, the immutability of lists makes NetLogo programming more approachable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone else, what I did in the end was use a new agent breed 'orders' in place of the matrix, with each orders turtle essentially being what would have been a row in the matrix. I told the orders to sit on the same patch as the turtle that owned it, which was easy as the turtles in that model don't move. The advantage is that I had access to a wide range of processing possibilities that I didn't have with the matrix. Of course if you do this and the order of the rows matters, you need to include some way of managing this (something like `orders-own [index]` would do).